# Как передать base64 кодированную строку через GET?

Tags: php, http, url, base64

Адресная строка браузера имеет вид:
http://example.com/file.php?p=cFji1OAi0BZOpG4V/UnD+PW5x02noySnDX0V1YAJKNA=
Данные закодированы с помощью `base64_​encode()`.
Но, принимается строка уже как: `cFji1OAi0BZOpG4V/UnD PW5x02noySnDX0V1YAJKNA=`,
знак `+` заменяется на `пробел` будто бы используется `urldecode()`

Чем кодировать base64 кодированную строку для передачи через GET?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: @Etki, если вы имеете в виду использовать `urlencode()` чтобы перевести пробел в плюс при получении GET-данных, то не получится, в строке могут встречаться: `/` или `=`, последний она изменит на `%3D`, что опять не позволит раскодировать dase64 строку.

Comment: А вы просто str_replace замените пробел на +, в base64 других вариантов быть не может

Comment: Ну либо перед передачей замените + на любой нормально передаваемый символ, отсутствующий в base64 и при приеме замените его обратно

Comment: @Mike, я думал об этом. Как насчет подводных камней, только пробел на плюс или могут быть еще какие-то символы изменены (мне не до конца известны символы на выходе из base64)? Так понял специальной функции для такого случая не существует.

Comment: @Mike милая магия костыля

Comment: @Plush при отправке, а не при получении. При получении она автоматом декодируется.

Comment: @Plush base _64_, считаем 10 цифр + 26 маленьких + 26 больших букв - итого 62 символа. не хватает двух - это (в обычном base64) `/` и `+`, и еще знак `=` не входящий в кодировку, но используемый в конце как заполнитель не кодированных байт.

Comment: @Etki, при получении пробел сохраняется :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Агрегирую все, что сказал ранее.

HTTP, понятное дело, не поддерживает все символы в URL - скажем, разрешенный пробел сломал бы заголовок HTTP-запроса:

```
GET /wow wow wow HTTP/1.1
```

Парсер знает, что первым словом идет метод, вторым - путь, третьим - версия протокола, а последующий обработчик откажется обрабатывать запрос с протоколом "wow", потому что такого протокола банально не существует.

Поэтому существует экранирование символов, о чем буквально стыдно не знать. Экранирование символов превращает символы в безопасные последовательности, декодировать которые - задача принимающего обработчика. В PHP это декодирование выполняется из коробки.
Есть (как минимум) два основных стандарта экранирования, про которые никто не знает, когда какой применять - это plus-encoding и percent-encoding. Первый заменяет все пробелы на символ "+", который вы кормите своему обработчику, который вполне справедливо ожидает на входе экранированных данных (потому что только человек, незнакомый с HTTP будет пытаться передавать данные не согласно стандарту HTTP), и, конечно, будет превращать этот плюс в пробел. И %20 превратит в пробел тоже. Потому что так работает HTTP, **потому что данные перед отправкой нужно подготовить (экранировать)**. В PHP, как я сказал, это делается тупо вызовом функции `urlencode()` (есть еще `rawurlencode()`, но выяснение различий в RFC я оставлю для тех, кто любит таким заниматься):

```
echo urlencode('cFji1OAi0BZOpG4V/UnD+PW5x02noySnDX0V1YAJKNA=');
//              cFji1OAi0BZOpG4V%2FUnD%2BPW5x02noySnDX0V1YAJKNA%3D
```

После этого у вас наконец есть возможность отдать обработчику то, что он ожидает:

```
http://localhost:8000/index.php?var=cFji1OAi0BZOpG4V%2FUnD%2BPW5x02noySnDX0V1YAJKNA%3D

// index.php
// <?php
//
// echo $_GET['var'];

cFji1OAi0BZOpG4V/UnD+PW5x02noySnDX0V1YAJKNA=
```

Comment: В принимающем скрипте есть строка: `echo $_GET['p'];` Я специально передаю сроку из вашего примера в адресной строке браузера, вот она: `cFji1OAi0BZOpG4V%2FUnD%2BPW5x02noySnDX0V1YAJKNA%3D` и в принимающем скрипте получаю вот это: `cFji1OAi0BZOpG4V/UnD PW5x02noySnDX0V1YAJKNA=` Вы уверены в своем примере обработки? Ибо я не выдумываю и это реальные данные. В чем тут проблема, конфигурации?

Comment: @Plush какой фреймворк используется, какие обработки проходит запрос до попадания в PHP?

Comment: mod_rewrite используется. Да, если его не использовать. то обрабатывается корректно, но, к сожалению, такая передача принципиальна. Скрипт передает как: example.com/p/base64_string, где base64_string - строка кодированная base64. Правило: `RewriteRule ^p/(.*)/{0,1}$ file.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Почему же mod_rewrite препятствует корректной обработке с urlencode?

Comment: @Plush попробуйте добавить флаг NE (`[QSA, NE, L]`). Вообще убивать за такое поведение надо, если это и вправду оно.

Comment: Добавил.Перезапустил. Не хочет. Проблема в этом, это точно. Передача напрямую `file.php?p=` срабатывает с urlencode, сомнений нет.

Comment: @Plush попробуйте еще флаг [B](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b)

Comment: Да, с B срабатывает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34071/discussion-between-plush-and-etki).

Answer (score 0):

Функцией `urlencode`. Только делать это нужно там, где этот URL строится.

У вас значение `p` в [строке запроса](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) содержит URL-неэкранированные символы, так что случиться может что угодно. Адрес изначально должен иметь следующий вид:

> http://example.com/file.php?p=cFji1OAi0BZOpG4V%2FUnD%2BPW5x02noySnDX0V1YAJKNA%3D

Все потенциально небезопасные символы (в вашем случае `/`, `+` и `=`) можно употреблять в строке запроса только в их "процент-записи", иначе корректный разбор попросту нельзя гарантировать.

Answer (score 0):

Кодировать/декодировать строку в base64 для передачи через GET, используя пользовательские (самописные) функции вместо base64_encode() и base64_decode():

```
function base64url_encode($data) { 
  return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
} 

function base64url_decode($data) { 
  return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT)); 
}
```